# Queries involving data passed via JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

Ok, so I have a function that takes a `JSONB` type, and performs `SELECT` and `INSERT` based on various keys from that blob of data. PostgreSQL is throwing up errors regarding the `PERFORM` and `INSERT`. What's the correct usage of json data in SQL queries?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_revision(d jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    did INT;
BEGIN
    did:=get_drawing_id(d->>'Name');
    IF did=NULL THEN
        did:=create_drawing(d->>'Name',d->>'Discipline',
            d->>'Doc Type');
    END IF;
    PERFORM * FROM revisions WHERE drawingid=did AND Sequence=d->>'Sequence';
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO revisions (Sequence,Revision,State,Meta) VALUES(d->>'Sequence',
            d->>'Version',d->>'State',d);
        RETURN jsonb_build_object('ok',true);
    END IF;
    RETURN jsonb_build_object('ok',false,'message','Already exists');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is the error throw up

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42883]: Un
defined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text
LINE 1: ... * FROM revisions WHERE drawingid=did AND Sequence=(d->>'Seq...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare an integer with a text. PostgreSQL is strict.

Check for types in this section.

```
 drawingid=did AND Sequence=d->>'Sequence'
```

It shouldn't be a problem related to the JSONB.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to use JSONB functions in queries, I just had to typecast to the required type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_drawing_revision(d jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    did INT;
BEGIN
    did:=get_drawing_id(d->>'Name');
    IF did<0 THEN
        did:=create_drawing(d->>'Name',d->>'Discipline',
            d->>'Doc Type');
    END IF;
    PERFORM * FROM revisions WHERE drawingid=did AND Sequence=(d->>'Sequence')::INT;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO revisions (Sequence,Revision,State,Meta) VALUES((d->>'Sequence')::INT,
            d->>'Version',d->>'State',d);
        RETURN jsonb_build_object('ok',true);
    END IF;
    RETURN jsonb_build_object('ok',false,'message','Already exists');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```